# Understanding base_url parameter when using HybridAuth

Tags: php, oauth, oauth-2.0, openid, hybridauth

I'm trying to use the hybridauth library to authenticate and get access to the users profiles of my corporate OpenID provider.

I'm trying to configure all the parameters but I don't understand some of them:

- What exactly is the base_url parameter ?? the help says: **'base_url' the url that point to HybridAuth Endpoint (where index.php and config.php are found)** But i'm having troubles to find this files or figure out what it means.
- What exactly do I need to ask my provider to configure properly my OpenID adapter using the hybridauth library ??

Answer (score 2):

When you install hybridauth, it will contain a folder named 'hybridauth'. That's where you will find the index.php and config.php files by default.

If you install this hybridauth folder in your web-root, then your endpoint `$base_url` will be "http://yourhost.com/hybridauth/"